# what is the 'SEL' rule in SQL creating table and selections such as SEL(1/0)?

Tags: sql, teradata, create-table

I had a problem with how to use SEL in Teradata. The problem is asking what does SEL(1/0) do ?
Also, I had a piece of code like this:

```
CREATE  VOLATILE TABLE   VT_ADDRESSES
, NO FALLBACK, NO BEFORE JOURNAL, NO AFTER JOURNAL AS 
( SEL 
     1234  MEMBER_KEY 
    ,'1234 MAIN STREET'  STREET
    ,'DALLAS'  CITY  )
WITH DATA                                        
PRIMARY INDEX (  MEMBER_KEY     )
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO VT_ADDRESSES  SEL 1237  MEMBER_KEY,'3413 CABRIOLET CT', 'RICHARDSON' CITY;
```

in this case, I guess the table format is set according to

```
'( SEL 
     1234  MEMBER_KEY 
    ,'1234 MAIN STREET'  STREET
    ,'DALLAS'  CITY  )'
```

But I am not sure if this could cause truncation of later inserted information

```
'INSERT INTO VT_ADDRESSES  SEL 1237  MEMBER_KEY,'3413 CABRIOLET CT', 'RICHARDSON' CITY; '
```

the string 'RICHARDSON' is longer than the previous 'DALLAS' in SEL part.

Really need help with this.

Comment: There is no `SEL 1/0` in your code.

Comment: `SEL` is simply short for `SELECT` (legacy syntax). `SEL(1/0)` simply returns a *division by zero* error. In your Create Table the data types are based on the literals -> SMALLINT, VARCHAR(16) UNICODE, VARCHAR(6). Your 2nd insert will silently truncate the strings if it's run in a Teradata session, an ANSI session will fail. See `SHOW TABLE VT_ADDRESSES`

Comment: You need to either define your volatile table before loading data (and specify your column width), or, if you want to continue doing it the way you have it, you need to cast your literals - `cast('DALLAS' as varchar(x)), ...`